# How can I open the form that I created in HTML in a new window?

Tags: html, window, new-operator

I am trying to find out how to open a form (I already made in HTML) in a new pop-up window? I have tried many solutions and explanations, but nothing works? Here is my code:

```
<center>
<FORM NAME="tic" method="post" target="_blank">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME=".1.." class=".2.." value="    " style= "background-color:#00BFFF" onClick="if.......................
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME=".1.." class=".2.." value="    " style= "background-color:#00BFFF" onClick="if.......................
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME=".1.." class=".2.." value="    " style= "background-color:#00BFFF" onClick="if.......................
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME=".1.." class=".2.." value="    " style= "background-color:#00BFFF" onClick="if.......................
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME=".1.." class=".2.." value="    " style= "background-color:#00BFFF" onClick="if.......................
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME=".1.." class=".2.." value="    " style= "background-color:#00BFFF" onClick="if.......................
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME=".1.." class=".2.." value="    " style= "background-color:#00BFFF" onClick="if.......................
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME=".1.." class=".2.." value="    " style= "background-color:#00BFFF" onClick="if.......................
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME=".1.." class=".2.." value="    " style= "background-color:#00BFFF" onClick="if.......................
</form>
</center>
```

BTW: The dots are not actually in my code (which works the way I want it to). They are examples that are used in place of my code.

Comment: How are you opening your form at the moment? With an `<a>` tag? With a modal? Also, you appear to have identical `name` attributes which won't work, and your inline handlers should really be swapped out for unobtrusive JavaScript.

Comment: what different methods have you tried? Just to refine solutions to results you haven't yet tried.

Comment: It's better to use modal than popup. You can read about modals here, https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp